# Saving an e-mail attachment to a UNC path

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have the following code in a VSTO add-in I'm writing for Outlook:

```
        savefolder = Regex.Replace(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"[- ]", String.Empty);

        savepathfull = string.Format(@"{0}{1}", netloc, savefolder);
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@savepathfull);
        if (!(di.Exists))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@savepathfull);



        removedFiles = new List<string>();

        for (int d = attachs.Count; d > 0; d--)
        {
            if (attachs[d].Size > smallAttachment)
            {
                removedFiles.Add(attachs[d].FileName);
                attachs[d].SaveAsFile(savepathfull);
            }
        }
```

Everything works fine until I try to save the attachment, at which point I receive an UnauthorizedAccessException.  I know that my test user has full rights to the folder, yet I still receive this error.

Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: which line throws the exception? can you also post the exception message and stack trace?

Comment: I would also try deleting the directory thats there and see if it errors on the Directory.CreateDirectory wrap that if statement in {} so that you may want to do additional things it's better to wrap it in a Try catch don't assume that the code will not error.. if it  returns an error then it's probably a rights/permissions issue do you have access to the network share or folder..?

Comment: I'm confused by your implementation. Is `savepathfull` a file or a directory? You seem to be using it as both _(`Directory.CreateDirectory(@savepathfull);` and `attachs[d].SaveAsFile(savepathfull);`)_.

Comment: @SliverNinja - Outlook.Attach.SaveAsFile uses the path as its variable.

Comment: @AdamRalph - attachs[d].SaveAsFile(savepathfull)

Comment: @DJKRAZE - i have full rights, and the directory is created without issue

Comment: I think you might want to look at the Path.* operations. When you send the full file path to a create directory method, you may create a directory with the full file path. So you can't create the file, since it's already a directory. Or @SilverNinja's concern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide a valid filename when calling `Attachment.SaveAsFile`. You are trying to save to a directory, not to a file. See MSDN for [reference code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210277%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

```
attachs[d].SaveAsFile(Path.Combine(savepathfull, attachs[d].DisplayName);
```

Comment: Agreed with @AdamRalph.  The IDE only states (string path) as a variable.  I guess I should've checked MSDN first.